# How import object from external JS file in React JS using web pack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I am building on my knowledge of React JS and I would like to import/include some external JS files that hold nothing more than an objects / object arrays. I've done this in jQuery, Vanilla JS and even in Angular JS. Sweet!!!

How can I achieve the same thing in React JS.

I have the following as my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello React</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hello"></div>
        <div id="world"></div>

        <div id="caseListing"></div>

        <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my main.js (entry file) as the following:

```
import Hello from './jsx/hello.jsx';
import World from './jsx/world.jsx';

var $ = require('./lib/jquery.js');
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

var Jobs = require('./data/jobs.js');
console.log('Jobs:', Jobs);
```

Here, I have Jobs.js as:

```
var Jobs = (function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        "jobs": [
            {
                "jobType": "Web developer",
                "desc": "Creates website"
            },
            {
                "jobType": "Bin Man",
                "desc": "Collects bins"
            }
        ]
    };
}());
```

And just for good measure, my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './js/main.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'js/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        'es2015',
                        'react'
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

All help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 28):

You need to export Jobs from jobs.js in order to import it into another module.  And jobs.js doesn't need to be a function if your just exporting static data.  So, you can make jobs.js look like this:

```
export default {
    jobs: [
        {
            jobType: "Web developer",
            desc: "Creates website"
        },
        {
            jobType: "Bin Man",
            desc: "Collects bins"
        }
    ]
};
```

Then you can import it like so:

```
import Jobs from './data/jobs.js';
```

Or:

```
var Jobs = require('./data/jobs.js').default;
```

If you want to require with normal commonjs syntax then you can make jobs.js like this:

```
module.exports = {
    jobs: [
        {
            jobType: "Web developer",
            desc: "Creates website"
        },
        {
            jobType: "Bin Man",
            desc: "Collects bins"
        }
    ]
};
```

Which allows you to require like so:

```
var Jobs = require('./data/jobs.js');
```

Comment: How if the file contains some variables declared and functions also using those variables? Can you give an example for that.

Comment: What if my jobs.js is an autogenerated file by a third party app that I don't have any control over? (i.e. cannot add the module.exports to it)

Answer (score 24):

Let's say the file you're keeping your data in is called "file.js."

```
var text = "Hello world!"; //In file.js
```

Below this line, You must export this variable so that it can be imported in the React code:

```
module.exports = {data: text} //In file.js
```

The string is stored as an object called "data." 
You then import the contents of "file.js" in the file you wish to use it, let's say App.jsx".

```
import file from './file.js'; //In App.jsx
```

The contents of the object you exported in the other file is being stored as the variable "file" here. You can then convert the contents of "file" to an object:

```
var str = file.data; //"data" is the object within "file"
```

Your string, "Hello world!", is now stored within the variable str.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if my file.js is an autogenerated file by a third party app that I don't have any control over? (i.e. cannot add the module.exports to it)