# Unable to use jQuery function call from a different .js file in componentdidmount() of react component

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have been learning jQuery for quite sometime and so far it's been good. But there is one thing I am stuck on. I did try to get answers before putting this question up but those weren't helpful in getting me the solution I was really looking for.

I am trying to call a jQuery function from one of my jQuery function files. Let me give you an example of what I am trying to achieve here.

I have my react_component.js which contains react and jsx code.

React_component.js

```
        import React from 'react';
        import {render} from 'react-dom';

        export class Home_page extends React.Component{

          render(){
            return(
              <section className="home-sections">
                <div className='home-div'>
                  <h1>Hello, I am home page</h1>
                </div>
              </section>
            );
          }

          componentDidMount(){
             //console for some reason doesnt work here.

             animate_component();           //Jquery function call
          }
        }
```

jQuery file home.js

```
    animate_component(){
       alert("animate the 'sections' component");
       //Some animation code needs to execute
    }
```

Errors I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: animate_component is not defined
at React_component.componentDidMount
```

Basically I want to execute .js files specific to each component (page). I am trying to build a SPA using react and with jquery i have added some on-screen animations which I want to execute only when the respective component gets rendered. So when home page is rendered, only run the code from home.js, and not others. Same goes for other pages.

Also, just to make it more clear, i have bundled several .js files into one. For e.g, scripts for home page have been bundled altogether, same for other pages, so to picture this without react, it would be, for home page I am running only 1 bundled home.js file instead of multiple .files, for about page, 1 about.js file. So to re-iterate my question, when home page is rendered, run functions only from home.js, when about page is rendered, run functions only from about.js.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this medium [post](https://medium.com/@shuvohabib/using-jquery-in-react-component-the-refs-way-969de9aa651f), you can import jquery as `import $ from ‘jquery’;` , define your function using jquery (he makes one called `handleToggle`), and then integrate it in dom like `onClick={this.handleToggle}`.

Note that using ids and classes to manipulate dom simultaneously is discouraged. Also a discuss thread that might be useful [here](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/jquery-with-react/683)
There seems to be lots of materials around.

Comment: So my jquery.js file is in the js/ folder and not the node modules. So instead of import $ from 'jquery', i can use import $ from './js/jquery.js'. Is that acceptable?

Comment: i dont think that can be done because you are loading from npm if you have done `npm install --save jquery`

Comment: onClick={this.handleToggle}, still in doubt about on click, i want the function to execute when the element is rendered... :/

Comment: I just tried " import $ from './js/jquery.js " and i think it might have worked since m not getting any error related to $ not found. Only error which is persistent is the one indicated in the question.

Comment: I am not sure if i have been clear enough, but i need the jquery to run some interactive and non-interactive functions, declared in separate .js files, based on which component is mounted. I still seem lost regarding the answer posted :/

Comment: Maybe this answer is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218507/1304575

Comment: :/ I think this is for importing the objects. What i have done is i have added different functionalities, animations etc. which need to work only when Home_page component is mounted, not otherwise. All these functionalities along with few variables are in a particular .js file meant to run only upon the mounting of the Home_page component.

Comment: yes i get that. but instead of trying to access them directly via function calls, you can declare them as exports and import them in your file and then use the functions. (check the next answer in the same link). You can import anything, not just objects, provided you declare them that way. similar to importing jquery stuff (except here you import yours)

Comment: I tried the import export method as mentioned in the link provided, not sure if it worked, but when i navigated to say about page using react router, i wanted functions from about.js to run, i.e when about_page component would mount, functions from about.js should run. So in about_page.js, i added `import file from ./about.js`. But nothing is happening. :/

Comment: M not sure what i am missing :/

Comment: I exported the method that needs to execute when the  About_page component gets mounted, but it just doesnt work :/