# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when importing an array

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an app for a class, and the professor is just as confused as I am about why it's not working. I have 2 js files and one html. I'm exporting an array from one js to the other, then using that js as the src in my html. Here's the pertinent code:

**medList.js:**

```
export const CompleteMedList = [
.....
];
```

**main.js:**

```
import {CompleteMedList} from './MedList.js'
```

**html:**

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

And here's the error I'm given:

> main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I tried using type="module" in the script tag, but then it gives me this error when I try do do stuff using the functions declared in main.js:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: openCycleForm is not defined at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Here's the function that the error references in main.js:

```
function openCycleForm() {
   document.getElementById("newCyclePg1").style.width = "100%";
   for (var i=0; i < CompleteMedList.length; i++){
       document.getElementById("fullMedsList").innerHTML += 
       "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"meds\" id=\"" + CompleteMedList[i].id + "\">" +
       CompleteMedList[i].name + "<br></br>";
   }
}
```

I initially had the code in the html file (where it worked), but just moved it to main.js so I could use an array of data instead of hardcoding it, and then everything broke...

Comment: may not solve your entire problem, but for 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: openCycleForm is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" 
have you made sure that your JS file is loaded before the html document if the html is being manipulated by the JS? And/or that your JS uses something like document on load when interacting with the DOM?

Comment: Hey can you give some more thorough samples of the code. It's hard to tel what's going on from tiny tid bits. Also, format the code correctly :]

Comment: I'm going to sound dumb, but how do I make sure the JS file is loaded before the html file? It sounds like that might be the issue. If it is, then I can keep the tyep="module" in there.

Comment: I did that, and then it gives me Uncaught ReferenceError: openCycleForm is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: There's an issue with your functions in `main` then, as `type="module"` solved the other error. If it's not much code add it here, or add it on jsFiddle so we can have a quick look.

Comment: when you do `import {CompleteMedList} from './MedList.js'` i think you are saying is "create a object `CompleteMedList` from the object im fetching from './MedList.js'" if you remove the curly brackets the problem persist? or maybe try adding "default" in the export like `export default const CompleteMedList`

Comment: Just edited to add a function in main.js

Comment: Where's your `onClick` listener? Is it in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, the onClick is in the html. Here's a link to a jsFiddle I just started: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=jFqeRKMr6z. I couldn't add the array js, but it's really simple.

Comment: Try the solution here for exporting and see if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218507/9636451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's being a bit funny with the inline JS, so I suggest you remove it and add the event listeners in `main.js` instead. Something like this which I have working locally on my machine at the moment:

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="currentCycle">Current Cycle</button>
```

JS

```
const currentCycleButton = document.querySelector('.currentCycle');
currentCycleButton.addEventListener('click', openCurrentCycle, false);

function openCurrentCycle() {
  document.getElementById("currentCycle").style.width = '100%';
  console.log('done');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! It messed with some of my CSS, but I can work with that.